# Assigning new attributes to a factor variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am newly beginning to work in R and running into some issues dealing with factor variables. In this case it's a very simple task of finding a distribution of numbers in an otherwise complicated dataframe. I am working with someone else's code and I would like to implement this in a seamless way.

I have a datatable`dt` with a bunch of different columns, one of which is a variable `num`, which I am interested in making a histogram of. But I want to make this histogram with some weird set of bins:

`binEdges = c(0:25,100,1000,Inf)`

The code that was previously written to do this is

```
dt[,orderc=cut(num,binEdges)
dt[,count:=.N,by=orderc]
```

they then proceed to only keep unique rows and a few other things.

What I want to do is make a new column, `normcount`, which normalizes the counts for the bin size.
I can get the sizes by calling

```
binSizes = diff(binEdges)
```

but now I want to make a new column in `dt`, where the value of `count` gets divided by the appropriate `binSize`. But how do I make it look up "which bin the current row corresponds to"? I would do this in Python probably by using some kind of dictionary but here the factor variable output by the cut() function is really unwieldy, and I'm not sure how to work with it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Most of what I've tried so far has involved taking the data out of the data table and treating it as individual vectors, but I think there should be a neat way to do it within the data table. I just can't see it!

Comment: Instead of telling a novel on what you are doing, just make a small self-contained example, as described in our [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick with `factor` variables is that they are internally represented as integers (by default 1 to number of categories), with an extra `labels` attribute giving the string name.  So they kind of act like numbers and kind of act like strings.

If you want to use the factor as a lookup into a table, you can force it with `as.numeric()` or `as.character()`, and then use it as an index into a vector (R tends to use named vectors where Python would use a dictionary.)

Some care is needed with your example, as the last bin has infinite size, so dividing by the size is not likely to get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. Indeed the value for the last column will be 0, but that's intended. I'm trying to build a probability distribution and the density in an infinite bin should indeed be 0.